# Rendering multiple classes/objects via React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

In one React file, I have the following:

```
 ReactDOM.render(
   <BlogButton />,
   document.getElementById('nav-blog--react')
 );

 ReactDOM.render(
   <NavButton />,
   document.getElementById('nav-home--react')
  );

  ReactDOM.render(
   <PoweredByButton />,
   document.getElementById('nav-powered--react')
  );
```

Only the first render works: the "BlogButton" shows up. The other two, "NavButton" and "PoweredbyButton" don't show. I'm not getting an error in the console either. Is that because you can't have multiple renders in a file? How would I combine all of these then into one render call?

Comment: Should work. Do you get any error messages in the developer console?

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/swrc9hja/ What version of React are you using?

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: I have stuff like <nav id="nav-home--react"></nav> in my template.

Answer (score -1):

Although I can't explain you WHY your example doesn't work - from what I know and have read in the react documentation the "go-to" method is creating 1 main/wrapper component which contains everything else.

You can see the wrapper component as your new DOM to which you append new elements.

I suggest you to create one wrapping component which gets rendered directly into the DOM. While the other elements are rendered within the wrapper component.

```
WrapperComponent
...
render(
<div>
<FirstComponent />
<SecondComponent />
</div>
);


ReactDOM.render(
   <WrapperComponent />,
   document.getElementById('nav-powered--react')
  );
```